# Mover aquivos por extensão, PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, script, lógica

Boa tarde,

Estou afim de afinar minhas habilidades em PY, e estou em um pequeno script para mover arquivos de um lugar para o outro, porém gostaria de fazer isso e não me guiar pelo nome do arquivo, mais sim pela extensão do mesmo, exemplo *.pdf ou *.doc, porem como sou novato em python ainda não sei ao certo qual função utilizar para isso.

Segue meu codigo (incompleto ainda falta a logica de mover arquivos)

```
# Ordernar arquivos Area de trabalho

import os

nameUser = os.getlogin() # Capturando nome do usuario
desktop_user = 'c:\\Users\\'+nameUser+'\\Desktop'
os.chdir(desktop_user) # Mudando para DESKTOP do usuario logado no momento

######### Funções #########

# Função criada para criar diretorios caso eles não existam
def criarDir():
    dirDoc = ['Documentos PDF', 'Documentos WORD','Documentos EXCEL',
              'Documentos TXT', 'Outros Arquivos', 'Multmidia']
    for dir in dirDoc:
        if not os.path.exists(dir):
            os.makedirs(dir)
        else:
            print('Diretorio {} ja existe !' .format(dir))
    return  dirDoc
def moveArquivos(listaDir):
    fileList = ['.doc','.docx', '.xlsx', '.txt', '.pdf', '.xls', '.csv',
                '.ppt', '.pps']
    fileMidia = ['.jpg', '.jpeg','.mp3', '.wav','.mid', '.mp4', '.mov']



    #for file in fileList:
     #   if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar o nome do arquivo e descobrir a extensão dele:

```
nome_do_arquivo = '/home/user/pudim.jpg'
file_splited = nome_do_arquivo.split(".")
extension_name = file_splited[-1]
print(extension_name) # OUT: 'jpg'
```

Esse código divide o nome do arquivo em uma lista, onde o `.` define o fim daquele elemento e inicia um outro.
A mágica de pegar a extensão, está no `file_splited[-1]`, onde ele pega o ultimo elemento da lista.

Comment: for file_stat in lista_arquivos_desktop:
        contaChar = 0 # Criado para obter a posição atual do indice, e assim ser usado para obter a extensao do arquivo
        word_temp_list = list(file_stat) # ira conter a lista da atual palavra do looping atual
        for char in word_temp_list:
            if char == '.':
                extensao = file_stat[contaChar:] # Obtendo a extensao do arquivo
                arquivo_bruto = file_stat
                aux_moveArquivo(extensao, arquivo_bruto)
            contaChar += 1